# fail2ban has banned my Ip but I can still login using SSH

Tags: fail2ban

I done a fresh new install of `fail2ban` on a Debian 9.8

I copied `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` as `jail.local`.

And in my `jail.local` in added `enabled=true` under `[ssh]`

Tailing fail2ban's log I can see what happens when I try to login to SSH using a wrong username/password pair

```
2019-03-13 17:03:55,751 fail2ban.filter         [3328]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.168.229.1
2019-03-13 17:03:55,753 fail2ban.filter         [3328]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.168.229.1
2019-03-13 17:03:57,534 fail2ban.filter         [3328]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.168.229.1
2019-03-13 17:04:00,630 fail2ban.filter         [3328]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.168.229.1
2019-03-13 17:04:00,633 fail2ban.filter         [3328]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.168.229.1
2019-03-13 17:04:00,635 fail2ban.actions        [3328]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 192.168.229.1
```

I supposed it was ok, but I can still try to login. I got

```
2019-03-13 17:07:59,245 fail2ban.actions        [3328]: NOTICE  [sshd] 192.168.229.1 already banned
```

And I see my Ip into iptables

```
 sudo iptables-save | grep 192.
-A f2b-sshd -s 192.168.229.1/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

So, why I can still try to login? I can also, of course, do a successful login using right name/pwd pair.

I am using the port 26522 instead of standard 22 for ssh. Must I precise it in someway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reason was the port.

I changed into my `jail.local`, inside the section `[sshd]` the port

```
port = ssh
```

into

```
port = 26522
```

And reloaded

```
sudo /etc/init.d/fail2ban reload
```

It worked immediately !